# Using CHOICE with CMD script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

Having trouble getting this CHOICE script to work. Can anyone provide any insight?

```
@echo off

CHOICE /C:IRCQSH /T 10 /N /M "Waiting with choice..." /D H

IF ERRORLEVEL 0 ECHO "Default choice: Health"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO "Install"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 ECHO "Remove"
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 ECHO "Console"
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 ECHO "Quit"
IF ERRORLEVEL 5 ECHO "Start"
IF ERRORLEVEL 6 ECHO "Health"

pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your syntax to treat `ERRORLEVEL` as a variable, and use the CMD equality statements, such as:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 ECHO "Default choice: Health"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 ECHO "Install"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 ECHO "Remove"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 3 ECHO "Console"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 4 ECHO "Quit"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 5 ECHO "Start"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 6 ECHO "Health"
```

The reason your code is failing is, taken from [here](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html):

> IF ERRORLEVEL n statements should be read as IF Errorlevel >= number
>
> i.e.
>
> IF ERRORLEVEL 0 will return TRUE when the errorlevel is 64

Comment: Woah! I didn't know that!   I have read that url link a few times before but somehow skimmed over that; it was easy to miss.  In the past I had used "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0", which is the same as using EQU right?

Comment: That will do a string comparison of "0"=="0" instead of 0==0, but yes, it should accomplish the same.

Answer (score 2):

A couple points here:

- The default choice does NOT return an ERRORLEVEL of zero, but the number of the choice selected. In your case, that is H, the default is equal to press H with an ERRORLEVEL of 6
- The right way to take the value of ERRORLEVEL is enclosing it in percents and use the EQU comparison, as LittleBobbyTables said in his answer. However, there are other ways to achieve the same result.
- The `IF ERRORLEVEL Number Command` test if the errorlevel value is Greater or Equal than the given number, so you may also use this form:

.

```
@echo off

CHOICE /C:IRCQSH /T 10 /N /M "Waiting with choice..." /D H

FOR %%E IN (6 5 4 3 2 1) DO IF ERRORLEVEL %%E GOTO LABEL-%%E

:LABEL-1 
ECHO "Install"
GOTO CONTINUE

:LABEL-2
ECHO "Remove"
GOTO CONTINUE

:LABEL-3
ECHO "Console"
GOTO CONTINUE

:LABEL-4
ECHO "Quit"
GOTO CONTINUE

:LABEL-5
ECHO "Start"
GOTO CONTINUE

:LABEL-6
ECHO "Health"

:CONTINUE
pause
```

- Perhaps the simplest way to achieve the same thing is defining an array and show the appropriate element using the errorlevel value as index:

.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create an array with the desired messages (selected by numeric index)
set index=0
for %%a in ("Install" "Remove" "Console" "Quit" "Start" "Health") do (
   set /A index+=1
   set elem[!index!]=%%a
)

CHOICE /C:IRCQSH /T 10 /N /M "Waiting with choice..." /D H
echo !elem[%ERRORLEVEL%]!
pause
```

For a further description of Batch arrays, see: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)